# lwip - what's the reason tcp socket blocked in send()?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, nonblocking

I am make a application base on lwip,the applcation just send data to the server;
When my app works for some times (about 5 hours),I found that the send thread hung in send() function,and after about 30min send() return 0,and my thread run agin;
In the server side ,have make a keepalive,its time is 5min,when my app hungs,5min later the server close the sockect,but my app have not get this,still hungs in send() until 30min get 0 return; why this happen? 
1: the up speed is not enough to send data,it will hungs in send?
2: maybe the server have not read data on time,and it make send buff full and hungs?

how can i avoid these peoblems in my code ? I have try to set TCP_NODELAY,SO_SNDTIMEO and select before send,but also have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

`send()` blocks when the receiver is too far behind the sender. `recv()` returns zero when the peer has closed the connection, which means you must close the socket and stop reading.

Comment: For my app,just send data ,and select very short time (10ms) to read.In fact,the server don't send data back,just read.At first ,I guess maybe the server send data,i have not read and block server first,so I try to aways read when my thread is idle,but no data readed.

Comment: Define 'no data read'. What happened instead? Blocked? `EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK`? `recv()` returned zero?

Comment: I make select before read,select no data,so have not run recv();And I check with the server agin,and found that when my app hungs in send,the server is trying to close the socket,but can not close.it seems that FIN data can not send or reiceve.... so this is the reason my app blocked for long time. How is it happened?

Comment: You're going to have to post the code. Your `select()` code could be wrong for example. Have you tried it in blocking mode, without the `select()` and just a blocking-mode `recv()`?